# Reuse result of "where" command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to find the specific location of java 64-bit on a windows machine. I thought about using `where java` to find all possible locations. In the next step I would need to isolate the proper location which starts with: `C:\Program Files\Java\...` and then execute the command as following:

```
cmd /K %var% -jar %~dp0XYZ.jar
```

Is this the proper way to find the java path which might change over time? If yes, how can I get the path from `where` into a variable?

---

For the output of `where` assume this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\java.exe
```

It wouldn't matter if it takes second or third result, as both are 64 bit in this case. But as I can't guarantee that output, the only way to identify the 64-bit version is with `C:\Program Files\Java\`

Answer (score 0):

The following `bat` script (commented for explanation) should do the trick:

```
@ECHO OFF
rem SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_flagexe64=:\Program Files\Java\"
set "_javaexe64="

for /f "delims=" %%G in ('where java.exe') do (
  rem next two lines for debugging only
  echo checking "%%~G"
  "%%~G" -version
  if not defined _javaexe64 (
    set "_javaexe64=%%~G"
    call :check64
  )
)

rem final check
if not defined _javaexe64 (
  1>&2 echo sorry, no java.exe found under "%_flagexe64%"
  goto :eof
)
rem java.exe found:
echo "%_javaexe64%"
goto :eof

:check64
  call set "_aux=%%_javaexe64:%_flagexe64%=%%"
  if "%_aux%" == "%_javaexe64%" set "_javaexe64=" 
goto :eof
```